# What is the difference between counter-set and counter-reset in CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-counter

I've recently been trying to automatically number headings for my Notion writing. The usual implementation I found on the [Internet](https://www.bitdegree.org/learn/css-counters) is like this:

```
body {
    counter-reset: chapter;
}

h1 {
    counter-reset: subchapter;
}

h1::before {
    counter-increment: chapter;
    content: "Chapter " counter(chapter) ". ";
}

h2::before {
    counter-increment: subchapter;
    content: counter(chapter) "." counter(subchapter) " ";
}
```

As can be seen, one can use `counter-reset` to initialize a counter. But when I use this same implementation in Chrome for Notion (via this [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-javascript-and-css/nbhcbdghjpllgmfilhnhkllmkecfmpld/related)):

```
body {
    counter-reset: headings1;
}
div.notranslate[placeholder="Heading 1"] {
    counter-reset: headings2;
}
div.notranslate[placeholder="Heading 2"] {
    counter-reset: headings3;
}

div.notranslate[placeholder="Heading 1"]::before {
  counter-increment: headings1;
  content: "Chapter " counter(headings1) " ";
}
div.notranslate[placeholder="Heading 2"]::before {
  counter-increment: headings2;
  content: "Section " counter(headings2) " ";
}
div.notranslate[placeholder="Heading 3"]::before {
  counter-increment: headings3;
  content: counter(headings2) "." counter(headings3) ".";
}
```

it just can't work. The result is like this:

```
Chapter 1 <should be Chapter 1>
    Section 1 <should be Section 1>
        0.1 <Should be 1.1>
        0.1 <Should be 1.2>
        0.1 <Should be 1.3>
    Section 1 <should be Section 2>
        0.1 <should be 2.1>
        0.1 <should be 2.2>
        0.1 <should be 2.3>
Chapter 2 <should be Chapter 2>
    Section 1 <should be Section 1>
        0.1 <Should be 1.1>
        0.1 <Should be 1.2>
        ...
```

However, if I use `counter-set` (in a weird manner), everything works again:

```
body {
    counter-set: headings1 headings2 headings3;
}

div.notranslate[placeholder="Heading 1"] {
    counter-set: headings2;
}

div.notranslate[placeholder="Heading 2"] {
    counter-set: headings3;
}

/*body {*/
/*    counter-reset: headings1;*/
/*}*/
/*div.notranslate[placeholder="Heading 1"] {*/
/*    counter-reset: headings2;*/
/*}*/
/*div.notranslate[placeholder="Heading 2"] {*/
/*    counter-reset: headings3;*/
/*}*/

div.notranslate[placeholder="Heading 1"]::before {
    counter-increment: headings1;
    content: "Chapter " counter(headings1) " ";
}
div.notranslate[placeholder="Heading 2"]::before {
    counter-increment: headings2;
    content: "Section " counter(headings2) " ";
}
div.notranslate[placeholder="Heading 3"]::before {
    counter-increment: headings3;
    content: counter(headings2) "." counter(headings3) ".";
}
```

Does this mean that one should use `counter-set` instead of `counter-reset` to initialize a counter? And what is the difference between `counter-set` and `counter-reset`?

I appreciate that this is a weird question and the source of the problem may be a bug or something. But if you know anything about counters in CSS, please share your knowledge:)any kind will help.

Comment: I think `counter-set` is for setting the initial value, `counter-reset` updates a counter to the specified value. So in your first snippet, you keep resetting the subchapter counter back to 1.

Comment: share your html code, we need to see the code structure to give a proper answer

Comment: The html code is like this:
`<div class="notranslate" spellcheck="true" placeholder="Heading 1" ...> ... </div>`
So I use the selector `div.notranslate[placeholder="Heading 1"]`

Comment: I agree with you Barmar, but there are so many posts on the Interset that use `counter-reset` for initialization. I guess in some cases `counter-reset` will work but `counter-set` is instead the proper choice.

Comment: Could you include the HTML for the above example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, you should create a new counter with `counter-set` and only use `counter-reset` if you want to reset an existing counter. Note that `counter-reset` will create a new counter if there isn’t one already, so, in reality, there’s not much in it under normal circumstances.

However there is some confusion when you do a `counter-reset` on a sibling rather than on a parent. I think what’s happening here is that you are creating a new counter with the same name, which is why it isn’t incrementing the way you expected. In this matter Firefox and Chrome appear to have a different interpretation of what should be happening.

There is some discussion on https://github.com/mdn/browser-compat-data/pull/15666 about the specification.

The other thing is that Safari doesn’t support `counter-set` at all. For my purposes I just use `counter-reset`.

Answer (score 0):

As stated on [Mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counter-reset#description) it is very counter intuitive. `counter-reset` should be used for creation and `counter-set` for value adjustment

> After creating a counter using counter-reset, you can adjust its value by using the counter-set property. This is counterintuitive because, despite its name, the counter-reset property is used for creating and initializing counters, while the counter-set property is used for resetting the value of an existing counter.

Answer (score -1):

In CSS, both `counter-set` and `counter-reset` are used to manipulate CSS counters, which are a way of generating automatic numbering or counting elements in a document. However, they serve slightly different purposes:

1. **counter-set**: This property is used to set the value of a counter to a specified integer. It allows you to explicitly set the initial value of a counter, overriding any previous value it might have had. If the counter does not already exist, `counter-set` will create it. This property is useful when you want to initialize a counter with a specific value, typically at the beginning of a document or a section.

   Example:

   ```css
   .section {
       counter-set: section-counter 1; /* Initialize section-counter to 1 */
   }
   ```
2. **counter-reset**: This property is used to reset the value of a counter to a specified integer, typically zero. Unlike `counter-set`, `counter-reset` does not create a new counter if it doesn't already exist; instead, it resets the value of an existing counter or initializes it to zero if it hasn't been used before. `counter-reset` is commonly used to reset counters at the start of a new section or element.

   Example:

   ```css
   .section {
       counter-reset: section-counter; /* Reset section-counter to 0 */
   }
   ```

In summary, `counter-set` is used to explicitly set the value of a counter, while `counter-reset` is used to reset the value of a counter or initialize it to zero. Both properties are useful for controlling the behavior of CSS counters and generating automatic numbering or counting of elements in a document.